# "In xx years" vs "In xx years' time"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Hi I am a English learner, and am confused with the following expressions:

> 1. "In xx years", and
> 2. "In xx years' time"

What's the difference between the two? Thank you.

Comment: 'In two years' time' has the specific meaning of 'at a date two years from now'.